# Is there a Whitney-type theorem Cauchy manifolds?

Tags: gn.general-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be a [Cauchy space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_space) whose induced topological space is a second-countable Hausdorff space that is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Does it follow that there exists a subspace $N$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a function $f : M \to N$ such that $f$ is a Cauchy-continuous bijection whose inverse is also Cauchy-continuous?

If no, what other conditions would be sufficient/insufficient to conclude this?